# Why Doesn't the DOM Update When an MFE Remote Application is Hosted in the Application Shell?

Tags: angular, webpack, nrwl-nx, micro-frontend

This question is regarding and angular application with a micro frontend architecture.

The remote application has a data table and filters, where the filters are hidden in an expansion panel. When the remote application is accessed via http://localhost:4201, everything behaves as expected; the filters expand/hide and the data table sorts, paginates, etc.

When the remote application is hosted within the shell application then any table sorting, pagination, filter expansion, etc. do not work. To get the DOM to update accordingly then the *Click Me!* button at the top of the page needs to be clicked. That button is nothing more than a modal window, but when rendered that also renders the other DOM updates on the page.

To code is viewable at: https://github.com/Astrofyziky/srm

1. Clone the following repo: https://github.com/Astrofyziky/srm
2. Navigate to the workspace and run **npm install** in the terminal
3. Run the project by typing **nx run dashboard-shell:serve-mfe** within the terminal
4. Open Chrome and navigate to http://localhost:4201.
5. Try out table sorting, filtering, and pagination features. This is the expected behavor.
6. Navigate to http://localhost:4200/data-grid
7. Click on *Select Filter Criteria* just once. Notice how it doesn't expand.
8. Click on the button in the upper left corner labeled *Click Me!* Notice how the filters expand now.
9. Choose a state filter. Notice how the *results* found changes, the *show results* changes, and the *pagination* (at the bottom of the page) changes; implying the events are firing and the DOM is only partially being updated.
10. Click on the *Click Me!* button again and notice how the DOM updates how it should have in step 9.

Answer (score 0):

BrowserModule is being imported into too many modules and libraries.  It's only necessary for BrowserModule to be imported into the shell application.